# Filtering on views

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a question about an MS SQL query.
I have following data which I would like to filter:

```
+----+----------+-------+-----------+    
| Id | Location | Store |  Result   |    
+----+----------+-------+-----------+    
|  1 | AB       |     1 | Executed  |    
|  2 | AB       |     1 | Cancelled |    
|  3 | AB       |     2 | Executed  |    
|  4 | AB       |     2 | Missing   |
|  5 | AB       |     2 | Executed  |    
|  6 | CD       |     3 | Cancelled |    
|  7 | CD       |     3 | Executed  |    
|  8 | EF       |     4 | Missing   |    
|  9 | EF       |     4 | Cancelled |    
| 10 | GH       |     5 | Cancelled |    
+----+----------+-------+-----------+
```

I want to achieve this result:

```
+----------+-------+----------+    
| Location | Store |  Result  |    
+----------+-------+----------+
| AB       |     1 | Executed |    
| AB       |     2 | Executed |    
| CD       |     3 | Executed |    
| EF       |     4 | Missing  |    
| GH       |     5 | Cancelled|    
+----------+-------+----------+
```

Following selection criteria have been applied:

- If a result contains 1 line, pick that status (ID 10)
- If results have the same Location & Store:

  - If the group has 1 line with Executed status, pick that status
  - If the group has multiple executed lines, pick 1 line with executed status no matter what order

The data in every group will always be the same, so for this example, a GROUP BY Location, Store would be enough, if it wasn't for the criteria I want.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the rationale for selecting `Missing` as opposed to `Cancelled` for `EF`?

Comment: This can be random, I just need to get the first result (I don't really get this decision but that's what I have been asked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Row_number to pick one row per combination, like so:

```
Select Location, Store, Result from
  (Select Location, Store, Result
    , Row_Number() over (partition by Location, Store 
            order by case Result when 'Executed' then 1 else 2 end) as RN
from Table
  ) a
where RN = 1
```

As mellamokb noted, you will probably want to add more options to the case statement if you don't want it to randomly choose a result when there are no "executed" rows.

Comment: Thanks! A quite easy solution, why didn't I think of this earlier! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` with a modified `ORDER BY`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                PARTITION BY Location, Store
                ORDER BY
                    CASE Result
                        WHEN 'Executed' THEN 1
                        WHEN 'Missing'  THEN 2
                        ELSE 3
                    END
            )       
    FROM TestData
)
SELECT
    Location, Store, Result
FROM Cte
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! A quite easy solution, why didn't I think of this earlier! :D